# Suggest a reading list to start TQFT

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

What would be books that would give the necessary prerequisities to study TQFT? I want to read something like Kock's Frobenius algebras and 2d TQFTs, I only know enough math that got me through a graduate degree in physics. Suppose I only know high-school math

Comment: You need to know a bit about bordism theory (not a lot : just the definitions) and some category theory to begin with. Even then all of this won't make sense unless you know some algebraic/differential topology, etc, which would help you see how powerful TQFTs are as diffeomorphism invariants of $(d+1)$-manifolds. I recommend the first few chapters of Lurie's lectures notes for a lucid introduction.

Comment: *I only know enough math that got me through a graduate degree in physics. Suppose I only know high-school math.* These are two rather bewildering statements. I suggest you elaborate on your mathematical background a little further. Surely you know linear algebra and multivariate calculus?

Comment: I dont really know more linear algebra and multivariate calculus then you can learn in a week or so. Youre right that I took such courses, but I havent used anything I learned and have forgotten most of it.